# How to use Google icon web fonts?

Tags: css, google-webfonts

I'm following the instruction in [Google's Material Icons Guide](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/) but for some reason it does not work when I tested it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Charlie/p95c1ow3/). The icon/image of a face do not show up.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<i class="material-icons md-48">&#xE87C;</i>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to include the link to the font and then use it:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet">

<i class="material-icons">face</i>
```

working [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/sfd5ba1a/)

Comment: When I put the link in the HTML location, JSFiddle asked me to put into the external resources. That's where I put the link and I'm guessing that's why my version didn't work. Thanks!